# Why does my PR Curve look like this?

Tags: classification, roc, precision-recall

These are my recall and precision stats for the model I built. The Curve does not look good where recall is 0. Not sure why there are so many points there. Can anyone help and explain why the curve looks like that?

```
Recall Test: 0.24 Train: 0.68
Precision Test: 0.75 Train: 0.67
```

[image]

Comment: I would have thought recall of $0$ means no true positives (but some false negatives), which would make precision also $0$.  So instead your points on the left may be a tiny number of true positives with many more false negatives and another tiny number of false positives (all these points would have a small proportion of total positive predictions true or false).  The volatility of the two tiny numbers may be the cause of the various points there.

Answer (score 3):

Your curve looks pretty normal to me. Precision is expected be noisy at low recalls.

Precision  is given as $PPV = TP/PP$ [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_predictive_values), or the fraction of true positive to predicted positives. For lower thresholds (at low recalls), PP is low as only a few points are predicted as positive. As a result, the precision is noisy.

In this instance, the second-lowest value is a false positive and has a huge impact on precision because at that point there are only 2 positives, 1 of them incorrect, resulting in a precision of 50%.